# Detect if the syncing of files to Dropbox is finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

I noticed that there is a delay after I used the `[self.restClient uploadFile: toPath: withParentRev: fromPath:];` and the `- (void)restClient: uploadedFile: from: metadata:` was called.

I'm using the Dropbox Core API v1 for iOS. Is there a function that tells whether the syncing of files is finished?

I'm assuming that the delay is where the sync is happening, am I correct to assume that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you mean by "syncing" here. When you upload a file via `uploadFile`, it will take some amount of time. When the upload is complete, the `uploadedFile` handler is called. The delay is the amount of time it takes for the upload to happen.

Comment: ahh... ok, i get it now. but when is the "syncing" happen?

Comment: I still don't know what you mean when you say "syncing," so I'm not sure how to answer.